# In a panel, how can you add multiple visual elements per logical child?

Tags: c#, wpf, panel, subclass

We have a custom Panel subclass where we're for each logical child that's added to it, we want to add two additional visual children.  If a logical child is removed, then we want to remove those two related visuals.  Internally we will map the logical element to the two additional visuals to keep track of all of this.

However, we can't seem to break the one-to-one relationship between the Children collection and the actual Visual Children in the panel's implementation.

Here's our first attempt, but we're not getting anywhere with this. We created a custom subclass of UIElementCollection which exposes a LogicalChildren collection. While this does display the proper items in the panel, the panel's Children property returns those visuals, not our LogicalChildren collection and we can't override Children.

We attempted to use the [ContentProperty] attribute on the class to point to a different property, which fixed it for the XAML, but we still have the children problem above.

We considered newing over it, but a user could simply cast down to Panel and get at the guts.

What we *want* is for the panel's Children property to hold only the logical things we've added to it externally.  The two additional visual items we don't want the user to have any access to (short of reflection or explicitly waling the visual tree that is.)

To recap, if we do this...

```
<TriVisualPanel>
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
    <TextBox />
</TriVisualPanel>
```

We want the logical tree to look like this (so if the user does Panel.Children.Count, they get three)...

```
TriVisualPanel
 - TextBox
 - TextBox
 - TextBox
```

...and the visual tree (used in the Measure and Arrange overrides) to look like this...

```
TriVisualPanel
 - TextBox
 - TextBlock <- Added dynamically
 - TextBlock <- Added dynamically
 - TextBox
 - TextBlock <- Added dynamically
 - TextBlock <- Added dynamically
 - TextBox
 - TextBlock <- Added dynamically
 - TextBlock <- Added dynamically
```

Here's our (mess of) code...

```
public class TriVisualPanel : Panel
{
    protected override UIElementCollection CreateUIElementCollection(FrameworkElement logicalParent)
    {
        return new TriVisualUIElementCollection(this, logicalParent);
    }       
}

public class TriVisualUIElementCollection : UIElementCollection
{

    public TriVisualUIElementCollection(UIElement visualParent, FrameworkElement logicalParent)
    : base(visualParent, logicalParent)
    {
        LogicalChildren = new Collection<UIElement>();
    }

    private Collection<UIElement> LogicalChildren;

    private void CreateTriVisualsForLogicalElement(UIElement logicalElement, int index)
    {
        [Faux code to create the three visuals here...]
        base.Insert(index, newVisualA);
        base.Insert(index, newVisualB);
        base.Insert(index,newVisualC);

        mapLogicalToVisuals(logicalElement, newVisualA, newVisualB, newVisualC);
       LogicalChildren.Add(logicalElement);
    }

    public override int Add(UIElement element)
    {
        CreateTriVisualsForLogicalElement(element, Count);
    }

    public override void Insert(int index, UIElement element)
    {
        CreateTriVisualsForLogicalElement(element, index);
    }

    public override void Remove(UIElement element)
    public override void RemoveAt(int index)
    public override void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        bla bla...
    }

}
```